# Locus of a moving point

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

Let $f(x),g(x)$ be Differentiable functions in their respective domains. Let $m(x)$ be a function whose perpendicular distance from $f(x)$ is always $g(x)$.Then, whats the equation of $m(x)$ in terms of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.

For example: Let $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$

$g(x)=sinx$

$m(x)=?$

Comment: Do you mean vertical distance? I can't make sense of your set up otherwise. Even if you do mean vertical things are still unclear as, being a distance, g(x) is positive and cannot be sin(x).

Comment: below the graph?

Comment: If the difference between m(x) and f(x) is always g(x) then m(x) - f(x) = g(x) or f(x) - m(x) = g(x). In the first case m(x) = f(x)+g(x) and in the second case m(x) = f(x) - g(x). Is that the kind of thing you mean?

Comment: $\mod{m(x)-f(x)}=g(x)$, both